# What environment do I need for Testing Big Data Frameworks?

Tags: hadoop, cloud, bigdata, distributed-system

As part of my thesis i have to evaluate and test some Big Data Frameworks like Hadoop or Storm. What minimal setup would you recommend to get some relevant Information about Performance and scalability? What Cloud Plattforms would be best suitable for this? Since im evaluating more than one Framework a out of the box PaaS - Solution wouldnt be the best choice. right? Whats the minimal number of nodes/servers to get some relevant Information? The cheaper the better, since the company im doing it for wont probably grant me a 20 Machine Cluster ;)

thanks a lot,
kroax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're definitely going to want at least two physical machines. Anything like putting multiple VMs on one physical machine is out of the question, as then you don't get the network overhead that's typical of distributed systems.

Three is probably the absolute minimum you could get away with as being a realistic scenario. And even then, a lot of the time, the overhead of Hadoop is just barely outweighed by the gains.

I would say five is the most realistic minimum, and a pretty typical small cluster size. 5 - 8 is a good, small range.

As far as platforms go, I would say Amazon EC2/EMR should always be a good first option to consider. It's a well-established, great service, and many real-world clusters are running on it. The upsides are that it's easy to use, relatively inexpensive, and representative of real-world scenarios. The only downside is that the virtualization could cause it to scale slightly differently than individual physical machines, but that may or may not be an issue for you. If you use larger instance types, I believe they are less virtualized.

Hope this helps.